# execute script when mobile device logs onto lan

Tags: network-monitoring

I am trying to find a way to execute a scripts on home computer as soon as a mobile device logs onto my home network. Fing and NMAP are the tools I need but trigger is posing a problem. Any suggestions.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question ("but trigger is posing a problem")?

Comment: When a new device comes online. I can't figure out how to get it to execute the script.

Comment: How do you detect that a new device has came online?

Comment: fing scan. 'fing 192.168.2.1/24' >scan.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DHCP, you might want to check & consider the following,

Sources:

Ubuntu Forums: [Run script after dhcpd assigned ip to client](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1328967)

SuperUser: [executing-a-script-when-dhcpd-give-an-ip](https://superuser.com/questions/211411/executing-a-script-when-dhcpd-give-an-ip)

dhcpd.conf

```
on commit {
        set ClientIP = binary-to-ascii(10, 8, ".", leased-address);
        set ClientMac = binary-to-ascii(16, 8, ":", substring(hardware, 1, 6));
        log(concat("Commit: IP: ", ClientIP, " Mac: ", ClientMac));
        execute("/usr/sbin/my_script_here", "commit", ClientIP, ClientMac);
}
```

Comment: This is great. But the machine that needs to execute the script is not the dhcp server.

Comment: Your script could contain/be something like `ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s' < local_script.sh`, combined with a ssh key without a passphrase (ugh). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine